# IBM BlueMix Free Plan Pricing

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I created a simple python flask application with 256MB to play around with.
They state that they give up to 2GB free of ram... so I was way below it

After 30 min I see that I'm billed $0.02..

[image: ibm bluemix free plan]

I tried to post it in their "stackoverflow" variant but I got 500 error :).. so my last resort is to ask here, maybe someone can clarify.

The fear will be to put an app there, forget about it, then at the end of the month you wake up with a $999 bill.

Comment: For specific billing questions, please open a Bluemix Support ticket - https://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport. 

You can also ask questions about your Bluemix account at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/topics/bluemix/?smartspace=bluemix. Stack Overflow is for technical programming questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand your concern, but I'm still going to try to help.

If you are afraid that you will be charged, this is not going to happen while you have the 30-days trial account. You will only have to pay if you decide to keep the account after the 30-days are over.

If you are afraid that you are being over-charged, you can always keep track of what you spent through the "View Full Usage Details", where there are all the pricing details (per region, per app, etc). You can also predict how much an app will cost beforehand using the calculator on the platform (https://new-console.au-syd.bluemix.net/?direct=classic/#/pricing/cloudOEPaneId=pricing&paneId=pricingSheet)

Lastly, if you are afraid that you will spend more than you want, there is a spending notification policy (which applies only to paid accounts, of course). I believe there is also an option to stop applications if they exceed a limit, but personally I haven't used these feature yet.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Not clear. They say they give xx GB/hour free for trial account without credit card and much more if I swipe the credit/debit card.  And I see that I'm billed even if I didn't use not even 1% of the free quota.  Let me tell you the following scenario. I go in holiday, no internet for couple of days. Meanwhile some hackers :) run a simple script that continuously make load on my apps or my clients apps. After few days how much the cost would it be ?

Comment: it's not about the 30 days trial. it's about what happens AFTER

Comment: Be aware that if you give them your CC info before the 30-day trial is over they immediately convert your account to a paid account and the trial is over.  I found out the hard way and lost 12 days of the free trial.  Also, even though on my billing page it shows no charges yet for TTS or STT services it does show a small dollar amount for services in the organization summary.  Huh?  My Bluemix Cloud Advisor assures me that I won't be charged anything so I guess I'll wait until the end of the billing cycle to see for sure.